# Wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, templates

I need to know how I can create WordPress page template that has this markup:

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="main-column-left">
     <div  class="map">
       <iframe></iframe>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="main-column-right">
   <h3>Contact us</h3>
   <p>blah-blah-blah</p>
   <p>blah-blah-blah</p>
   <p>blah-blah-blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [What have you tries](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

To create a template for wordpress create a php file example-template.php

Put the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: The name of your template 
 * Description: Your description
 */
get_header(); ?>

<!-- put here your html -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then upload the template to your theme folder and load it.